# KNP menu Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle

I'm having a hard time getting this to work, I get the following error:

> Unable to find template "KnpMenuBundle::menu.html.twig" (looked into: D:\Server\htdocs\symfonudem\app/Resources/views, D:\Server\htdocs\symfonudem\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form).

Below is my code for the Builder class.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

class Builder
{
  use ContainerAwareTrait;

  public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
  {
    $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Home', ['route' =>  'homepage']);


        return $menu;
  }
}

 ?>
```

And here is the code for the `base.html.twig`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        {% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
      {{ knp_menu_render('AppBundle:Builder:mainMenu') }}

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Your suggestions will be most appreciated.

Comment: have you created the twig file? the error is clear, it can't find the twig.
read https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
templating:
        engines: ['twig']
```

to the framework section in the config file

Answer (score 0):

You can state the full path to the menu builder as follows:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('AppBundle:Builder:institutionMenu', {'allow_safe_labels': true, 'currentClass': 'active' })|raw }}
```